# Disable hardware trackpad clicking

Tags: trackpad, click

My trackpad is broken, which causes the left-click button to get stuck. This results in a lot of unwanted clicking. Tap-to-click works fine and causes no issues.

Is there a way to disable the trackpad hardware, but not disable tap-to-click?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any way to disable the physical clicking of a 
Trackpad. The OS X trackpad preferences can be found [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201726), or by going to System Preferences -> Trackpad. If the Trackpad is constantly telling the OS to click, then there is little you can do to get around this. Trackpad replacements are $69, I believe, at the Genius Bar.